# root entries in last command

Tags: command-line, high-sierra, root

I ran the last command in my terminal on my macbook pro high sierra and in the output where entries for the root user. How is that possible? Should that user not be deactivated? Here are the entries for `last root`:

- root      console                   Thu Nov 30 09:31 - shutdown  (00:00)
- root      console                   Wed Nov 29 09:23 - shutdown  (00:02)
- root      console                   Wed Nov 22 19:00 - shutdown  (00:00)
- root      console                   Sat Oct  7 22:44 - shutdown  (00:00)

Thank you very much for your Help!

Answer (score 3):

These entries are fully normal.

The `shutdown` needs `root` priviledges to run, most notably to be able to kill all processes.
This doesn't mean that the `root` user logged on your system, and is totally independant of the fact that the `root` user is activated.

Comment: I have one question regarding this, I also have specifically shutdown entries that look like this `shutdown  ~                         Thu Nov 30 15:53` and I don't have any root entries on an other mac with version 10.9.5.. So what is the root accessory needed for? Could someone exploited the recent root bug on my computer?

Comment: @metro2012: On a Mac running `Mavericks`, you should also find entries like: `root      console                   Sat Aug 12 19:07 - shutdown  (00:02)` meaning that `root` id was used for 2 seconds and was a session ending on a shutdown of the system.

Comment: @metro2012: I suggest you to make a question about the `root` access vulnerability on `High Sierra`.